# Get an event when UIBarButtonItem menu is displayed

Tags: ios, menu, uibarbuttonitem

We all know how to make a simple tap on a bar button item present a menu (introduced on iOS 14):

```
    let act = UIAction(title: "Howdy") { act in
        print("Howdy")
    }
    let menu = UIMenu(title: "", children: [act])
    self.bbi.menu = menu // self.bbi is the bar button item
```

So far, so good. But presenting the menu isn't the *only* thing I want to do when the bar button item is tapped. As long as the menu is showing, I need to pause my game timers, and so on. So I need to get an event telling me that the button has been tapped.

I don't want this tap event to be *different* from the producing of the menu; for example, I don't want to attach a target and action to my button, because if I do that, then the menu production is a *different* thing that happens only when the user long presses on the button. I want the menu to appear on the tap, *and* receive an event telling me that this is happening.

This must be a common issue, so how are people solving it?

Answer (score 4):

The only way I could find was to use `UIDeferredMenuElement` to perform something on a tap of the menu. However, the problem is that you have to recreate the entire menu and assign it to the bar button item again inside the deferred menu element's `elementProvider` block in order to get future tap events, as you can see in this toy example here:

```swift
class YourViewController: UIViewController {
    
    func menu(for barButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem) -> UIMenu {
        UIMenu(title: "Some Menu", children: [UIDeferredMenuElement { [weak self, weak barButtonItem] completion in
            guard let self = self, let barButtonItem = barButtonItem else { return }
            print("Menu shown - pause your game timers and such here")
            
            // Create your menu's real items here:
            let realMenuElements = [UIAction(title: "Some Action") { _ in
                print("Menu action fired")
            }]
            
            // Hand your real menu elements back to the deferred menu element
            completion(realMenuElements)
            
            // Recreate the menu. This is necessary in order to get this block to
            // fire again on future taps of the bar button item.
            barButtonItem.menu = self.menu(for: barButtonItem)
        }])
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let someBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(systemItem: .done)
        someBarButtonItem.menu = menu(for: someBarButtonItem)
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = someBarButtonItem
    }
}
```

---

Also, it looks like starting in iOS 15 there's a class method on `UIDeferredMenuElement` called [`uncached(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uideferredmenuelement/3857602-uncached) that creates a deferred menu element that fires its `elementProvider` block every time the bar button item is tapped instead of just the first time, which would mean you would not have to recreate the menu as in the example above.

Comment: Ingenious as usual. I'll have to look into this.