# How to tell when a UIMenu gets DISMISSED

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uimenu

I have a UIButton with a UIMenu attached, I need to know when the UIMenu is dismissed (by tapping outside the UIMenu) so I can remove the button that the UIMenu is attached to.

I have seen there are notifications for UIMenuController, but that is different.

edit: Here's some additional info because this question was related to a different question.

I don't care when the UIMenu is called, I only care when it is dismissed

Comment: I understand your objection and I've reopened, but it's still really the same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69710316/get-an-event-when-uibarbuttonitem-menu-is-displayed (in another guise).

Comment: I had considered that, so I tried the implementation on that issue, but uideferredelement menu.uncached is only calling when the menu appears. not when its dismissed. But maybe im implementing it wrong.

Comment: I do not say the answer answers your question. I'm saying it's effectively the same _question,_ namely where are the signals when the menu appears / disappears?

Answer (score 2):

You have to create custom button (for call menu) and override its method `contextMenuInteraction(_:willEndFor:animator:)`. Add your action inside this method for removing the button that the UIMenu is attached to.

Comment: But can we also differentiate between:
a) User pressed in the background
b) User selected an option